# Rails 2.3.8: Errors in fetching records since MySQL is case-insensitive and Rails is case-sensitive

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, case-sensitive

I have 2 models with a one-to-one relationship (example is simplified and not the real models).

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student, :foreign_key => 'name', :primary_key => 'full_name'
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person, :foreign_key => 'full_name', :primary_key => 'name'
end
```

The link between them is a weak link, since one can change the full_name field in the Student object and then the person object couldn't be reached from the student object.

So far so good (this is by design).

The problem arises when a person's name is the same as an equivalent student's full_name, but different in the letters' case.

The query for the MySQL DB returns a result (since MySQL is case-insensitive),
but when Rails runs over the result it doesn't find it (since Rails is case-sensitive),
which results in an Error when eagerly loading the association.
Example of the error's stacktrace:

```
NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each):
  vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/association_preload.rb:155:in `set_association_single_records'
...
```

I'm guessing this is a Rails 2.3.8 bug.
Is there an easy solution for this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your controller code and the real models please?

Comment: They are confidential, but in the original code it's practically the same. Just different model names.

Comment: Your database design seems to assume there cannot be two people of the same name... this is why you should reference by IDs.

Comment: @sscirrus: As I said, this is a simplified example. With the original models, 2 objects will never have the same name, and this is also enforced on both keys in the models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not a Rails bug or a Ruby bug - Ruby strings are case-sensitive, so you should not expect this to work as is.

This is bad database design, but if you want to keep going down this road of madness, add a separate column `lower_name` to each table that has the name forced to lowercase and use that as your AR association link. (The cleanest solution is to put a `before_save` filter on each model to update `lower_name` when the name changes.)

Comment: Thanks!
This design is the result of the product team's demands for a specific situation.
Even though the design is a bit bad, I still believe this is a ROR bug since Rails isn't prepared for the fact that the DB would return more results than Rails is willing to accept resulting in an exception.

Comment: @Nadav, please remember that Rails is opinionated software. (MySQL is also opinionated software that often doesn't care about user expectations.) While it would be possible to have MySQL's ActiveRecord adapter introspect on the key column types and compare strings only after discarding case, this would slow down the adapter for the vast majority of Rails+MySQL apps that use a "sane" schema. You can always go down the path of extending the ActiveRecord MySQL adapter in your app to handle this scenario.